# Sed: save errors in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I am writing script, I need to use `sed` for changing somefiles, I want to know if the operation failed by an error such as "No Such File" could I save the error in a text file or in a variable? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the `stderr` by:

```
$yourcommand 2> log
```

- 0 means `stdin`
- 1 means `stdout`
- 2 means `stderr`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/Some Text/Something else/' $file > output 2>errors
```

This redirects the errors (from `stderr`, file descriptor 2) to the file `errors`.